# pass arguments from Qt to a shell script file

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shell, qprocess

I want to pass a string value from Qt codes to my shell script file called 'part1_4_md'. This is my codes from Qt:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QString path = ui->lineEdit->text();

    QProcess *process = new QProcess;
    process->start("/bin/bash", QStringList() << "/home/kha/Unix/QT/part1_4_md");
    process->waitForBytesWritten();
    process->waitForFinished();

    QString output(process->readAllStandardOutput());
    ui->textEdit->setPlainText(output); 
    QTextCursor textCursor = ui->textEdit->textCursor();
    textCursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, 1);

}
```

I created a lineEdit box and when the user types in the string value in that box and press the button, I need that value to be passed to my shell script file and the shell script file uses that value to run. This is what my shell script file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

files=($*);
dates=();

for (( i = 0; i<${#files[@]}; i++ ))
do
    dates[$i]=$(date -r ${files[i]} +"%Y%m%d");

done
```

The string value should be pass to '$*' to be used as an argument of the 'files' array. Please show me how to do this.

Comment: You should use http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setArguments and BTW you should not launch and wait on QProcess from UI thread. That is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are already passing your script as an argument to `/bin/bash` in string list via `arguments` parameter of [QProcess::start](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start). You can append more parameters to the list and bash should be able to interpret `path` as first argument for your script.

```
QString path = ui->lineEdit->text();
QString script("/home/kha/Unix/QT/part1_4_md");
QProcess *process = new QProcess;
process->start("/bin/bash", QStringList() << script << path);
```

If that doesn't work you could use `-c` option of bash.

```
QString path = ui->lineEdit->text();
QString script("/home/kha/Unix/QT/part1_4_md");
QString command_string = script + " " + path;
QString c_option("-c");
QProcess *process = new QProcess;
process->start("/bin/bash", QStringList() << c_option << command_string);
```

Note, that you are blocking your UI by waiting the process in the GUI thread. You could connect to [finished](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished) and [readyReadStandardOutput](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput) as well as error signals and run the process asynchronously or run it in a separate thread.